# Open Liberty 21.0.0.07 JMSActivation spect "Active" connections in the queue. There are two active connections in parallel and I want to limit to 1

Tags: jms, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, jca

Everytime my application starts up it is spinning two "active" MDB connections, and we want to restrict it to only 1 active while the rest should be inactive. I tried putting the following

```
maxPoolDepth="1"
maxMessages="1"
```

But still there are two active session every time I startup the application on Open liberty. Whereas it works fine only single thread on local developer's machine when he added maxPoolDepth="1". It only keep 1 session active at a time.

Also note when I change the `maxPoolDepth` to `0` on the server then there are no active connections, but when I change it to `1` it opens two active connections.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the number of concurrent messages being processed by the MDB ?  Or are you monitoring the number of connections somehow?  (Or both?)   Are you using MQ or Liberty embedded messaging as the JMS provider?

Comment: hi @ScottKurz , trying to limit the number of concurrent message processing, we want only 1 thread "active" for that queue., irrespective of number of connections.
using MQ at the backend.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same with OpenLiberty